# How to connect to an Oracle DB from a Python Azure Synapse notebook?

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse, ojdbc

I am trying to query an Oracle database from within an Azure Synapse notebook, preferably using Pyodbc but a pyspark solution would also be acceptable. The complexity here comes from, I believe, the low configurability of the spark pool - I believe the code is generally correct.

```
host = 'my_endpoint.com:[port here as plain numbers, e.g. 1111]/orcl'
database = 'my_db_name'
username = 'my_username'
password = 'my_password'

conn = pyodbc.connect( 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
'SERVER=' + host + ';'
'DATABASE=' + database + ';'
'UID=' + username + ';'
'PWD=' + password + ';')
```

Approaches I have tried:


Pyodbc - I can use the default driver available ({ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}) and I get login timeouts. I have tried both the normal URL of the server and the IP, and with all combinations of port, no port, comma port, colon port, and without the service name "orcl" appended. Code sample is above, but I believe the issue lies with the drivers.

Pyspark .read - With no JDBC driver specified, I get a "No suitable driver" error. I am able to add the OJDBC .jar to the workspace or to my file directory, but I was not able to figure out how to tell spark that it should be used.

cx_oracle - This is not permitted in my workspace.

If the solution requires setting environment variables or using spark-submit, please provide a link that explains how best to do that in Synapse. I would be happy with either a JDBC or an ODBC solution.

Comment: In case it's unclear, you would use `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` to connect to **SQL Server**, not to **Oracle**. To connect to Oracle with ODBC, you need Oracle ODBC drivers.

Comment: Why isn't cx_Oracle allowed?  If it's because of the requirement to install the extra set of Oracle client libraries, you should simply upgrade to the latest cx_Oracle version (renamed to python-oracledb) which doesn't need those libraries, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).

Comment: @JamesZ Yes, I noted that the issue is the driver - the problem is getting the Oracle driver to be accessible

Comment: @ChristopherJones Only certain approved software can be used, cx_oracle is not approved but the 19.X version of the Oracle JDBC driver is, as well as certain versions of the Oracle instant client and pyodbc.

Comment: That's a shame considering how popular Python is, and how small and functional the python-oracledb driver is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the .jar [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc8/19.15.0.0.1/) (ojdbc8-19.15.0.0.1.jar) to the Synapse workspace packages and then adding that package to the Apache spark pool packages, I was able to execute the following code:

```
host = 'my_host_url'
port = 1521
service_name = 'my_service_name'

jdbcUrl = f'jdbc:oracle:thin:@{host}:{port}:{service_name}'
sql = 'SELECT * FROM my_table'
user = 'my_username'
password = 'my_password'
jdbcDriver = 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'

jdbcDF = spark.read.format('jdbc') \
    .option('url', jdbcUrl) \
    .option('query', sql) \
    .option('user', user) \
    .option('password', password) \
    .option('driver', jdbcDriver) \
    .load()

display(jdbcDF)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).